# How to implement connection pooling within a process pool?

Tags: python, multiprocessing, python-asyncio, python-multiprocessing, aiohttp

I'm trying to make several million http requests efficiently. To do so, I've utilized [aiomultiprocess](https://aiomultiprocess.omnilib.dev/en/stable/guide.html#process-pools)  to run an asyncio event loop on each of my cpu processes.

My code looks like this:

```py
from aiohttp import request
from aiomultiprocess import Pool

async def execute_request(url: str, payload: dict = {}) -> tuple[int, dict]:
        """Execute the request and return the response status code and json response
        Args:
            url: url to query
            payload: dict of query params
        Returns:
            (status_code, json_response)
                status_code: int of the response status code
                json_response: dict of the json response
        """
        async with request(method="GET", url=url, params=payload) as response:
            status_code = response.status
            json_response = await response.json() if status_code == 200 else {}
            return (status_code, json_response)

async def api_pool_uploader(url_args):
    async with Pool(**pool_kwargs) as pool:
        async for result in pool.starmap(execute_request, url_args):
            if result is not None:
                await upload_to_db_function(result)

asyncio.run(api_pool_uploader(url_args))
```

This code works great for the first minute, but after executing about 1500 requests, the request function across all processes returns a `ClientConnectionError` and my computer drops all internet connections. As in, all the tabs in my browser start spinning, and no request from anywhere on my machine can get out. This lasts for about 45 sec, and then the internet resumes until I get through the next ~1500 requests, then it happens again...

I've confirmed that this is not my home internet going out (wifi on all other devices, etc remains stable throughout), nor is it the API throttling me. It seems to be an issue occur solely on my machine that is affecting the entire computer even outside of my python instances.

It is worth noting that this still occurs even when I scale down the number of processes in the pool to 1. Once it reaches about 1500 requests, all network requests drop even though it took much longer to get to the 1500 request mark.

If anyone has any idea what may be occurring, I'd love to hear it.

My primary suspicion is that aiohttp.request is creating a new "session" connection with each individual request. Having 1500 connections is perhaps overloading my computer's network adapter? (is that a thing?) And causing them all to drop and reconnect where possible?

To circumvent that, I'm trying to take advantage of connection pooling using aiohttp.clientsession, so that each request isn't opening an entirely new connection. However, I've been unable to do so.

The aiohttp [docs](https://docs.aiohttp.org/en/latest/client_reference.html) explain that the client session should be instantiated once for the entire scope of the app and then passing the `client` object as an arg into your request function. However, when spawning multiple processes, all args passed to the co-routine in the process pool must be serializable and importable. Attempting to do this, I receive this error:

```
AttributeError: Can't pickle local object 'WeakSet.__init__.<locals>._remove'
```

I've since tried to alter my code by making my own fork of aiomultiprocess to instantiate a clientsession for each worker when it is spawned, but that has resulted in the same error surprisingly.

This is what that code looks like:

```py
from aiohttp import ClientSession
class PoolWorker(Process):
    """Individual worker process for the async pool."""

    def __init__(
        self.client_session = ClientSession() #i added this
    )

    async def run(self) -> None:
    # I'm only showing the change I made to this function with relevant context
        task: PoolTask = self.tx.get_nowait()
        tid, func, args, kwargs = task
        args = [*args,self.client_session] #i added this
        future = asyncio.ensure_future(func(*args, **kwargs))
```

As I said before, this creates the same error...the client is unable to be pickled...

Is there anyway to utilize connection pooling while multiprocessing with a process pool? And if so, will it even help me solve my problem or am I barking up the wrong tree entirely?

Comment: what is the memory usage around the 1500~ request mark? Also, post the complete error traceback that occurs with ClientConnectionError